# Connect Oracle Database from SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem connecting to Oracle Database from SSIS.
I have successfully connected from Linked Server and I am able to pull the data from Oracle Database where I have used "Oracle Provider for OLE DB" for the connection.

But, in SSIS Connection Manager there is no "Oracle Provider for OLE DB" connection type.
It's showing "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle". Can I use that ? If I use "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle" getting error like

```
Oracle client and networking components were not found. 
These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the Oracle 
Version 7.3.3 or later client software installation.
Provider is unable to function until these components are installed.
```

I am trying from so many days.
Can you give me the solution to connect Oracle from SSIS ?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/989825a4-4660-4152-8de6-14db7d03ec69/oracle-client-and-networking-components-were-not-foundthe-components-are-supplied-by)?

Comment: i think the installation is not correct!

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić i have tried the things what you have shared link. My problem is not solved.

Comment: More people here on SO could help you if you write in your question exactly what have you tried and how it ended up.

Comment: I tired following things. 1. I have given a full control to Oracle Home Directory. 2. Restarted the system. 3. I have checked that there is no multiple copies of OCIW32.dll.

Comment: Can you give me the step by step process from starting of installation to success connection

Comment: @user1990383 Can you please confirm you are on SQL Server 2008? please note that this version of SQL Server is no longer supported by Microsoft, which means patches (including security patches) are not being provided.  Also, have you tried this: https://mindmajix.com/ssis/importing-from-oracle